# 'Bring [someone] on board [preposition?] [some project/plan]'

Tags: prepositions

Should I use a preposition after using the expression 'bring someone on board'? Like

> Paul made a powerful pitch, but he brought only a handful of colleagues on board [?] his eccentric plan.

Comment: You can use **with** in the blank.

Comment: For future reference, you could just enter a suitable sequence of up to 4 words plus a ***wild-card*** asterisk into the Google NGrams search box - for example, [on board * the plan,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+board+%2A+the+plan&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20board%20with%20the%20plan%3B%2Cc0) where the result clearly shows that we use ***with*** in place of that asterisk.

Comment: Also note that things change slightly if we switch the context to *Only handful of colleagues **agreed [?] Paul's plan***. A wildcard search for **agreed * the plan** would tell you that ***to*** and ***with*** are common prepositions there, but what it ***won't*** tell you is that ***no preposition at all*** is perfectly okay in that exact context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's the problem with using NGram. Okay, suppose this particular issue is now resolved, but I wouldn't have been able to figure out whether any preposition was needed in that case on my own using the suggested website

Comment: Not so. You'd just have to repeat the search without the asterisk, to see how often the four-word sequence [**on board the plan**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22on+board+the+plan%22) occurs. But I've just passed that string to Google *Books* rather than NGrams, so it needs to be enclosed in "quotes". It's easy enough then to see that any matches for **on board the plan** are just "accidental collocations" - whereas there are many instances of **agreed the plan**, showing that ***is*** a valid construction.